# Relative Path from Absolute Paths

Tags: actionscript-3, air

What's the easiest way to obtain a relative path from two absolute paths in ActionScript 3 using Adobe AIR?

e.g.

```
C:\my\first\folder
C:\my\second\folder
Relative Path from \first\folder to \second\folder:
..\..\second\folder
```

Comment: Try using [`File's getRelativePath()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#getRelativePath()) method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are:

```
var file1 : File = new File("C:\my\first\folder");
var file2 : File = new File("C:\my\second\folder");
var relPath : String = file1.getRelativePath(file2, true);
//relPath = ..\..\second\folder
```